# Postgres why do concurrent selects on the same table cause exclusive locks?

Tags: c#, postgresql

Postgres 9.6.5  Accessing through a c# application as a note in case this is for some reason related to ado.net.

1. Why does running a simple SELECT statement on a table concurrently cause locking?
2. Why does the above seem to only Sometimes cause 1 or 2 of the same jobs to hang indefinitely?
3. What is the appropriate way of concurrently querying a table without causing locks or at least Exclusive locks?

I made a test app to recreate the scenario.  It is executing the same Select query against a table concurrently.  Although it happens at different points each time this reliably recreates the same locking scenario which causes jobs to hang and ultimately an error of some kind in the background.

Here is the query being ran, the Vehicle table has roughly a little more than 1 million records:

```
select id, vin from vehicle;
```

I am running it in 10 concurrent threads 10 times for a total of 100 executions.  When executing, the service monitor looks like this.
[image]

I also tried using FOR SHARE:

```
select id, vin from vehicle FOR SHARE;
```

This seemed to help reduce how long the jobs remained but they still appear locked:

[image]

I'm having a difficult time understanding why multiple SELECT ONLY queries cannot execute concurrently on the same table, which is not being modified, without causing locks?

For the record this happens on other tables where we are using filter criteria  like "select all customers where dealer id = x".  This makes it appear that postgres isn't capable of supporting multiple concurrent queries on a table.  For as widely used as it is I find this hard to believe.

When it does error btw we get no information at all despite any error handling.  The app just enters "Break Mode".
[image]

Comment: Did you come up with any more information on this issue. We are running a PosgreSQL 9.6.11 RDS instance doing similar things. Large concurrent SELECT queries are starting to hang for no apparent reason. pg_locks shows that these queries are holding multiple "RowExclusiveLocks" which makes no sense for a pure SELECT query. If I clear everything out and run one of the queries manually, there are no exclusive locks created and the query finishes without issue. I'm currently testing the upgrade to 9.6.14.

Comment: Have you tried tuning the transaction propagation for the query to _never_ or _not supported_ ? Using the `@Transactional` annotation from spring-tx in Java you can do this: `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` or `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)`. I'm sure there's something similar in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't row or table locks. Each transaction takes out a lock on itself. Perhaps the clearest explanation I've read is here

http://rhaas.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/deadlocks.html?m=1

You aren't seeing any deadlocks of course, but people mostly get interested in locking when they hit a problem in their app.

Comment: The bummer here is that this issue causes the application to error, as the jobs never returns.  The link seems to explain things but gives no solution.  We see this even when selecting from the same table with filter criteria, e.g. where Id = x.  

Is the answer to the question, "Can postgres handle concurrent queries on one table?" really No?

Comment: All I can say is that this is something to do with your setup rather than postgresql. I've been using it for over 15 years and even when I started doing so it was happy  with this sort of concurrency. Are you happy that your network and server can transfer 100 x millions of records in a short period of time?

Comment: The answer is "of course it can". I've no idea what your problem is but it's not inside the database.

Comment: I agree, it has to be something in the configuration.  I used my test app to do the exact same thing on a MS SQL Server and it was able to complete.  I decided to change the parameters to 1 iteration of  10 concurrent threads since that is something the postgres instance could complete.  MS SQL Server came in 5 seconds faster at 33 seconds compared to Postgres 38 seconds.  Were running this in an AWS Aurora instance so I'm going to look into the configuration.  Too many people are using this successfully for it to be a problem with Postgres.